# jQuery not working on onclick change span text and display hidden table

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, toggle

I have a table like what I stated on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f6LyadLg/).
I would like to hidden the grey part at the very beginning. When the user clicked on "View Detail", the span text will be changed and the grey part will be displayed. And vice versa, when the user clicked on the "View Detail" again, the span text will be change back to the original shape and the grey part will be hidden.

I have tried to write some jQuery to deal with it but I have no idea why it is not working. Even the grey part cannot be shown... Does anyone has any suggestion on it?

```
$('.view-detail').on('click',function(){
   $('#table1 tr.show-history').css({"display":"block"});
   $(this).find('.right').text("&#9660;");
});
```

Editted based on suggestion by @Dinesh:
The toggle function only worked once for a click... how could I change it such that it will be toggle on every click?

```
$('.view-detail').click(function(){
   $('.show-history').toggle(function(){
        $('#table1 tr.show-history').css({"display":"block"});
        $(this).find('.right').html("&#9660;");
   }, function(){
       $('#table1 tr.show-history').css({"display":"none"});
       $(this).find('.right').html("&#9658;");
      });   
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not loaded jquery and use `$(this).find('.right').html("&#9660;");` instead of `$(this).find('.right').text("&#9660;");`

```js
var flag = false;
$('.view-detail').on('click',function(){
 $('#table1 tr.show-history').toggle();
   if( flag == false){
    $(this).find('.right').html("&#9660;");
     flag = true;
    }else{
     $(this).find('.right').html("&#9658;");
     flag = false;
    }
});
```

```css
#table1{
  background-color:white;
  width:500px;
}
.item-history{
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:#ebebeb;
}

.show-history{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
<tr class="view-detail">
  <td>
  <span class="right">&#9658;</span> View Detail
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="show-history">
<td>
<div class="item-history">
<table>
<tr><td>Row 1 History</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2 History</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 3 History</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Item 1 Description.........................................................................</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total: 1 Item</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Dinesh, Thank you for your suggestion. I have updated my post after adjusting something with your comment. Do you know how can I make it toggle on every click that I can hide and show the grey click... for my script currently it can only be displayed by once...